# How to find a document with maximum field value in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I have a number of Mongodb documents of the following form:

```
{
    "auditedId" : "53d0f648e4b064e8d746b31c",
    "modifications" : [
        {
            "auditRecordId" : ObjectId("53d0f648e4b064e8d746b31d"),
            "modified" : "2014-07-22 18:33:05"
        },
        {
            "auditRecordId" : ObjectId("53d0f648e4b064e8d746b31e"),
            "modified" : "2014-07-24 14:15:27"
        },
        {
            "auditRecordId" : ObjectId("53d0f648e4b064e8d746b31f"),
            "modified" : "2014-07-24 12:04:24"
        }
    ]
}
```

For each of these documents I want to find "auditRecordId" value which corresponds to the latest modification. In the given example I want to retrieve

`"auditRecordId" : ObjectId("53d0f648e4b064e8d746b31e")`

Or, even better:

```
{
    "auditRecordId" : ObjectId("53d0f648e4b064e8d746b31e"),
    "modified" : "2014-07-24 14:15:27"
}
```

Is there any way how I can do this without writing map-reduce functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you have an array in your document, the [`aggregate`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) method is your friend :)

```js
db.foo.aggregate([
    // De-normalize the 'modifications' array
    {"$unwind":"$modifications"}, 
    // Sort by 'modifications.modified' descending
    {"$sort":{"modifications.modified":-1}}, 
    // Pick the first one i.e., the max
    {"$limit":1}
])
```

Output:

```js
{
        "result" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("53d12be57a462c7459b6f1c7"),
                        "auditedId" : "53d0f648e4b064e8d746b31c",
                        "modifications" : {
                                "auditRecordId" : ObjectId("53d0f648e4b064e8d746b31e"),
                                "modified" : "2014-07-24 14:15:27"
                        }
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Just to illustrate the [`$unwind`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) operator, I used the above query with [`$limit`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/).  If you have multiple documents of the above format, and you want to retrieve the latest modification in each, you'll have to add another [`$group`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) phase in your aggregation pipeline and use the [`$first`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) operator:

```js
db.foo.aggregate([
    {"$unwind":"$modifications"}, 
    {"$sort":{"modifications.modified":-1}}, 
    {"$group":{
        "_id" : "$auditedId", 
        "modifications" : {$first:"$modifications"}}}
])
```